# Can't Clone Mesh created with CreateGroundFromHeightMap

Tags: babylonjs

I'm trying to `clone()` a `Mesh` created with `BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap()` but it never renders.

```
// Ground
var groundMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("ground", scene);
groundMaterial.emissiveTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("textures/earth.jpg", scene);

var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", "textures/worldHeightMap.jpg", 200, 200, 250, 0, 10, scene, false);
ground.material = groundMaterial;

// Cloned Ground
var groundMaterial2 = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("ground2", scene);
groundMaterial2.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
groundMaterial2.alpha = 0.5;

var ground2 = ground.clone("ground2");
ground2.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
ground2.material = groundMaterial2;
```

http://babylonjs-playground.azurewebsites.net/#YA6VT#1

Answer (score 0):

Since `CreateGroundFromHeightMap()` [loads its `VertexData` from an image](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/2e8dfdb58709be7f33c1f592351032bac71fdcc5/src/Mesh/babylon.meshBuilder.ts#L376-L407), the `Mesh` is not ready to be cloned until it has been loaded. By using `CreateGroundFromHeightMap`'s optional `onReady` parameter we can delay the `clone()` until everything is ready.

```
// Ground
var groundMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("ground", scene);
groundMaterial.emissiveTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("textures/earth.jpg", scene);

var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", "textures/worldHeightMap.jpg", 200, 200, 250, 0, 10, scene, false,
    mesh => {
        // Cloned Ground
        var groundMaterial2 = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("ground2", scene);
        groundMaterial2.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
        groundMaterial2.alpha = 0.5;

        var ground2 = mesh.clone("ground2");
        ground2.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        ground2.material = groundMaterial2;
    });
ground.material = groundMaterial;
```

http://babylonjs-playground.azurewebsites.net/#YA6VT#2